# SQL performance replace

Tags: sql, sqlperformance

I have the following query which I need to improve performance

```
DECLARE @number varchar(40) = '0800001001'
SELECT 
    Id 
FROM 
    Table1 
WHERE 
    (REPLACE(Phone1, ' ','') = @number)
OR (REPLACE(Phone2, ' ','') = @number)
```

The table has 500k rows and currently no indexes on these columns or full text.  Can anyone suggest the best way to improve this query using indexing, clr function or otherwise?

Comment: Are all numbers stored in same format? even if they have spaces do they follow a same pattern? If so then first thing you can do is to remove the REPLACE call and provide @number in same format as spaces

Comment: Try to run this query with **DataBase Tuning Advisor**. It is option in **SQL Management Studio**: Query\Analyze Query in ...., It will show you propositions of actions you can take up. This is first step to take.

Answer (score 1):

Create computed columns for `REPLACE(Phone1, ' ','')`, `(REPLACE(Phone2, ' ','')` and create index for these computed columns.

Comment: You may not even need to create the computed columns.  Depending on the SQL database being used, you can even create an index based on the replace expression. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html

Comment: Its SQL server 08.  I hadn't realised you could index a computed column.  Will try this and measure